# VirtualBox Share Guest Internet With Host

Tags: macos, network, wifi, internet, virtualbox

Recently I've encountered issue with My **MBP Mid 2009** Wifi Card,so I bought USB adapter but the problem is that it is not compatible with OSX only So I somehow managed it to Connect my guest **Virtual Box Windows 7** to Internet but I don't know how to share it with host, I've tried by Host-Only adapter but not sure how to share internet using that and I've tried some online articles but none of them shows how to setup Host OSX.

Currently I'm on *OSX 10.11.6* Host and **Windows 7 Guest**.

Screenshots of my Host Only network Setup.

[image: Guest Windows 7 Network]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please someone help....

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this working, you'll need to setup "Internet Connection Sharing" in the Windows 7 guest. You do it like this:

1. Open Control Panel => Network and Internet => Network and Sharing Center
2. Click Manage Wireless Networks in the left sidebar
3. Click on your USB WiFi connection, and then Adapter properties at the top
4. Select the Sharing tab and check "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection"

Now your Mac host should be able to use your virtual connection to the guest to access the internet. If you want, you can set the host to use DHCP on that connection to get IP address, gateway and DNS information automatically.